# pthread_create() : What is default priority and shceduling policy

Tags: linux, gcc, pthreads, nptl

The HP man page ([link](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51_HTML/MAN/MAN3/0537____.HTM)) says

> "By default, the new thread's scheduling policy and priority are
>   inherited from the creating thread---that is, by default, the
>   pthread_create(3) routine ignores the scheduling policy and priority
>   set in the specified thread attributes object.  Thus, to create a
>   thread that is subject to the scheduling policy and priority set in
>   the specified thread attributes object, before calling
>   pthread_create(3) your program must use the
>   pthread_attr_setinheritsched(3) routine to set the inherit thread
>   attributes object's scheduling attribute to PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED."

Is this hold true for Linux posix thread (NPTL pthread) ?

If not, what are the factors affecting priority and scheduling policy of a thread created using pthread_create() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_attr_setinheritsched):

> The following values may be specified in inheritsched:
>
> PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED 
>   Threads that are created using attr inherit scheduling attributes from the creating thread; the scheduling attributes in attr are ignored.
>
> PTHREAD_EXPLICIT_SCHED 
>   Threads that are created using attr take their scheduling attributes from the values specified by the attributes object.
>
> The default setting of the inherit scheduler attribute in a newly initialized thread attributes object is PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED.

So, seems to be the same behavior as the one described in the question.

I would actually have thought that such a default value could be defined by the standard (without having that much experience with that though, I'll admit), but looking at the last line of the [Thread Scheduling Attributes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html#tag_02_09_04) section:

> (...) The default values of other scheduling attributes are implementation-defined.